# изменение высоты и положения блока

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать контент вытянутым по всей высоте экрана , а получается что он выстраивается как нужно только после ресайза.И сайдбар который после скрола будет прилипать к той же позиции но , уже с левого верхнего края (т.к если делать fixed через css он прилипает в той позиции в которой он задается статически)
вот пример

js

```
fixed = document.getElementById('content');
window.addEventListener('resize',function(){      
            changeWindow = window.innerHeight;            
            fixed.style.height = changeWindow + 'px';         
       },false);
window.onload=function(){
                        changeWindow = window.innerHeight;            
            fixed.style.height = changeWindow + 'px';
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dirkdirk/ugcpv9pg/11/

Answer (score 1):

В вашем фиддле введённый вами скрипт сам выполняется по событию 'load':

[image: скрин фиддла]

Т.е. весь ваш скрипт выполняется уже *после* события `load` в фидле. Поэтому событие в вашем коде уже не поймать. А так вы всё сделали вполне работоспособно. Можно что-то улучшить:

Определяйте ф-ю всего один раз (сейчас код у вас повторяется дважды), 
и вызовите её сразу, а также навесьте на событие `resize`:

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');

var fit = function(){      
  content.style.height = '' + window.innerHeight + 'px';         
}

window.addEventListener('resize',fit);

fit(); // если этот скрипт вызывается уже по событию load

// или так, если не в jsfiddle и load ещё не наступил:
// window.addEventListener('load',fit);
```

[Фиддл](https://jsfiddle.net/ugcpv9pg/13/)

Comment: а как притулить сайдбар при скроле вниз ? повесить на него событие скрола и дать ему стиль fixed + подвинуть его вверх? для того что бы он был прикручен к верху

Comment: мыслите правильно. Можно и с самого начала дать ему `fixed`, а потом, по мере прокрутки, постепенно смещать вверх, чтобы не было рывков.

Comment: а как же учитывать размеры , если нужно что бы сайдбар прилипал именно когда пряталсяпотолок

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dirkdirk/ugcpv9pg/21/ таким образом почему то не работает(

Comment: Тема сайдбара заслуживает отдельного вопроса.